# Online service to create latex expressions and reference them

Tags: editors

I'm wondering if there's an online service where I can create a latex expression and then just copy a link to it and embed that link into another website?

Comment: You can do this with [the online LaTeX equation editor from Codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). Type in your equation and select URL from the menu at the bottom of the screen. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Wernerm, yeah, but it seems that all links point to an image, right?

Comment: What do you want it to point to then?

Comment: There's also [LaTeXiT](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17889/latexit), although this may be Mac specific.

Comment: @Werner, yeah,  probably that's the only thing that can be linked to. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the online LaTeX equation editor from Codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and select the URL from the bottom menu option. See, for example, [`f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c`](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?f(x)&space;=&space;ax%5E2&space;+&space;bx&space;+&space;c), which will point to a rendered imge.

---

Alternatively, another [online LaTeX equation editor from SciWeavers](http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor) allows the same. See, for example [`f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c`](http://www.sciweavers.org/tex2img.php?eq=f%28x%29%20%3D%20ax%5E2%20%2B%20bx%20%2B%20c&bc=White&fc=Black&im=jpg&fs=12&ff=modern&edit=0), pointing to another rendered image.

If you want to leave the user with an entered equation ready to be edited, use change the `edit=0` code in the above link to [`edit=1`](http://www.sciweavers.org/tex2img.php?eq=f%28x%29%20%3D%20ax%5E2%20%2B%20bx%20%2B%20c&bc=White&fc=Black&im=jpg&fs=12&ff=modern&edit=1).